# How are the difficulty level of a race determined?

Tags: midnight-club-los-angeles

I understand that the colour of the races, ranging from green to red, indicate the difficulty of the race.

What I would like to know is, does this include the level of traffic in that race?

And, does that include the opponents cars and modifications?

So if I drive up in my Audi B-Class vehicle, in a green race, will my opponents be matched in car type, or is the race just easier?

And separately, does any other modification on the car help in any way (ride height, wheel size, tyre type, spoiler)?